# Why extra value is printed using cout and printf?

Tags: c++, printf, cout, function-call

Why 5 is being printed after 1.00.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double x = 1;
    cout << printf("%.2f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

output :

1.00

5

Comment: I'll take care next time. Thanks

Comment: You could look up what [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) does and, in particular, what it returns.

Comment: i know what printf does, but i cannot understand why 5 is getting outputted

Comment: You could looke up what [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) does and, in particular, **what it returns**.

Comment: Hint: [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) returns the number of characters written.

Comment: okay got it now.

Comment: Can you use C++20? If so use [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) instead of printf (which is still kind of an "unsafe" leftover from C). format is faster and more typesafe then printf

Comment: I use c++14, will give it a try later.

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed as reproducible, voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C Standard (7.21.6.3 The printf function)

> 3 The printf function returns the number of characters transmitted, or
> a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred.

This call of printf

```
printf("%.2f\n", x)
```

outputs on console the following characters (shown as a string)

```
"1.00\n"
```

That is `5` characters including the new line character `'\n'`. The return value of the call is `5` according to the quote of the C Standard. And this value is outputted using the operator `<<` for the standard output C++ stream `std::cout`.